# CodeIgniter browser only display system_path and application_path

Tags: codeigniter, system-paths

My project works before in Ubuntu, but recently I moved it to Mac. After configuring Apache, the website finally doesn't give any errors. But the browser only displays:

```
$system_path = '../system'; $application_folder = '../application';
```

No matter what parameters I append the url, it gives the same result like above. When I installed CodeIgniter in Ubuntu, I got the same problem, eventually I solved it, but I forgot how to solve it. Please help me.

Comment: And what is your file/folder structure?

Comment: I would say you should move your `application` and `system` directories outside directory where `index.php` file is. I.e. if `index.php` is in `public_html` directory, `application` and `system` should be next to `public_html` and NOT next to `index.php` file.

Comment: @AnmolRaghuvanshi The structure is like:  <br/>   ---System  <br/>  ---Application  <br/>  ---public  <br/>  Core  <br/>  ...  <br/>  But it worked before like this structure in Ubuntu

Comment: @Tpojka It worked like this structure like my last comment, but I will try your suggestion.

Comment: @AnmolRaghuvanshi You are right!

Comment: I am right for what??

Comment: it must be @Tpojka :)

Comment: @AnmolRaghuvanshi , yes, I wanted to @ him, sorry about that.